# Drupal 7 - how to use jw player using videos located on a CDN

Tags: 7, media, cdn

We are currently using Drupal 6 and are in the process of upgrading to D7.

When I went to see if the module created by LongTail had a version compatible with D7 I found out that they don't have one, but they recommended to use this one:

http://drupal.org/project/jwplayermodule

The problem I'm currently facing is that I can't figure out how to use this module with videos that we already have in our CDN.

Any way to do this without having to upload my videos to the site?

Thank you,

Onema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar for [flowplayer](http://drupal.org/project/flowplayer). I had nodes created for legacy videos stored in Amazon S3 and added this code to the node--video.tpl.php:

```
 $mediaid = $content['field_mediaid']['#items'][0]['value'];
  if ($mediaid != '') {
      $video2 = '<a href="http://username.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/ka/'.$mediaid.'.mp4" id="player" class="flowplayer"></a>';
              flowplayer_add('#player', array(
                'clip' => array(
                  'autoPlay' => TRUE
                ),
              )); 

        print '<BR><BR>';
        print $video2;
```

There are other player options available as well, [video.js](http://drupal.org/project/videojs) seems to be more modern.

Comment: Great idea. I don't think I'll be using any modules from now on, I'll just add two custom fields for the video and another one for the image associated with it. and inserted the code in the template like you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: yeah, sometimes you don't need a module, even if "there is a module for that". I try to always keep things as simple as possible ;-)